# Count events in range on a vector via iteration in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, sampling

I have a vector that contains sample numbers of event markers. They are only listed when there is an event found, not at every sample. I would like to obtain an output of the number of events found every second. Sampling rate is known (15hz).

I figured out how to do it with a for loop, but it is working a bit on the slow side. I am struggling to figure out a more efficient way to perform this calculation (with mapply or something like that maybe?). Does anybody have any suggestions?

Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
vec <- c(9,20,23,48,50,51)
fs <- 15
start_idx <- seq(from=1,to=46,by=15)
end_idx <- seq(from=15,to=60,by=15)
counter <- vector()
for (i in 1:length(start_idx)) {
  counter[i] <- length(which(vec >= start_idx[i] & vec <= end_idx[i]))
}
```

The results of counter should be:

```
> counter
[1] 1 2 0 3
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

For a tidyverse approach, you can `map` inside `mutate`:

```
library(tidyverse)

ranges <- tibble(start_idx, end_idx)

ranges %>%
  mutate(ct = map2_int(start_idx, end_idx, ~sum(.x <= vec & .y >= vec)))

  start_idx end_idx    ct
      <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
1         1      15     1
2        16      30     2
3        31      45     0
4        46      60     3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `findInterval`/`cut` to find element in `vec` lies in which range and then use `table` to count frequency.

```
table(factor(findInterval(vec, start_idx), levels = seq_along(start_idx)))
#1 2 3 4 
#1 2 0 3
```